# Reading in strings that may contain spaces

Tags: c++

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Lab.cpp
// Author      : Neil Shah
// Version     : 001
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string stateCapital[50][50] = {
        {"Alabama" , "Montgomery"},
        {"Alaska" , "Juneau"},
        {"Arizona" , "Phoenix"},
        {"Arkansas" , "Little Rock"},
        {"California" , "Sacramento"},
        {"Colorado" , "Denver"},
        {"Connecticut" , "Hartford"},
        {"Delware" , "Dover"},
        {"Florida" , "Tallahessee"},
        {"Georgia" , "Atlanta"},
        {"Hawaii" , "Honolulu"},
        {"Idaho" , "Boise"},
        {"Illinois" , "Springfield"},
        {"Indiana" , "Indianapolis"},
        {"Iowa" , "Des Moines"},
        {"Kansas" , "Topeka"},
        {"Kentucky" , "Frankfurt"},
        {"Louisiana" , "Baton Rouge"},
        {"Maryland" , "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusetts" , "Boston"},
        {"Michigan" , "Lansing"},
        {"Minnesota" , "Saint Paul"},
        {"Mississippi" , "Jackson"},
        {"Missouri" , "Jefferson City"},
        {"Montana" , "Helena"},
        {"Nebraska" , "Lincoln"},
        {"Nevada" , "Carson City"},
        {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey" , "Trenton"},
        {"New Mexico" , "Santa Fe"},
        {"New York" , "Albany"},
        {"North Carolina" , "Raleigh"},
        {"North Dakota" , "Bismarck"},
        {"Ohio" , "Columbus"},
        {"Oklahoma" , "Oklahoma City"},
        {"Oregon" , "Salem"},
        {"Pennsylvania" , "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island" , "Providence"},
        {"South Carolina" , "Columbia"},
        {"South Dakota" , "Pierre"},
        {"Tennessee" , "Nashville"},
        {"Texas" , "Austin"},
        {"Utah" , "Salt Lake City"},
        {"Vermont" , "Montpelier"},
        {"Virginia" , "Richmond"},
        {"Washington" , "Olympia"},
        {"West Virginia" , "Charleston"},
        {"Wisconsin" , "Madison"},
        {"Wyoming" , "Cheyenne"}
};

int correctCount = 0;
string capital;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    cout << "What is the capital of " << stateCapital[i][0] << "?" << flush;
    cin >> capital;

    if (capital==stateCapital[i][1]){
        cout << "Your answer is correct" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The correct answer should be " << stateCapital[i][1] << endl;
    }
};

cout << "The correct count is " << correctCount << endl;
return 0;
```

}

I tried this program in JAVA but same error came. Talking about C++, the project runs fine but somewhere in my code there is bug that I cannot figure out. Below is the output of the program (note: not the entire output)

```
What is the capital of Alabama?Montgomery
Your answer is correct
What is the capital of Alaska?Juneau
Your answer is correct
What is the capital of Arizona?Phoenix
Your answer is correct
What is the capital of Arkansas?Little Rock
The correct answer should be Little Rock
What is the capital of California?The correct answer should be Sacramento
What is the capital of Colorado?
```

Is it having problems due to the spaces in some of the names? Is there something wrong in the way that I wrote this program? I had the exact same problem in the JAVA version too.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `java`?  The `cin >> capital;` gets one word at a time, separated by whitespace.  Maybe `getline` would work better here.

Comment: What is wrong? What is not working, in what way?

Comment: So you are reading single word but comparing with string containing two words. That consumes `Little` but leaves `Rock` for next iteration. In Java I suspect you used `Scanner#next()` instead of `Scanner#nextLine()` (BTW in Java you should not use `str1==str2` but `str1.equals(str2)`).

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `std::cin >> capital` will read a single space-separated token from the stdin. Just use `std::getline(std::cin, capital)` (and check for the error).

Comment: now it is saying "invalid overload of getline" it still does not work

Comment: getline >> capital;

Comment: @NeilShah See my answer.

Comment: @NeilShah -- Some advice -- why did you post all of this code with all of this data if your issue is only how to read in a string with a space?  A simple 3 line C++ program with *one* or *two* strings, demonstrating the issue that you're having is all you had to post.

Comment: You have declared `stateCapitals` as a 2D array of 50 x **50** `string`s, but you only need a 50 x 2 one. Even better, you could use a `std::map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By decault, [`cin.operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) cuts off at whitespaces (space, tab, newline). To read a whole line, use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
// Replacement for "cin >> capital"
std::getline(std::cin, capital);
```

Or, since you've declared `using namespace std;`, you can omit the `std::` prefix:

```
getline(cin, capital);
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is working, replaced the `cin` with `getline` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string stateCapital[50][50] = {
        {"Alabama" , "Montgomery"},
        {"Alaska" , "Juneau"},
        {"Arizona" , "Phoenix"},
        {"Arkansas" , "Little Rock"},
        {"California" , "Sacramento"},
        {"Colorado" , "Denver"},
        {"Connecticut" , "Hartford"},
        {"Delware" , "Dover"},
        {"Florida" , "Tallahessee"},
        {"Georgia" , "Atlanta"},
        {"Hawaii" , "Honolulu"},
        {"Idaho" , "Boise"},
        {"Illinois" , "Springfield"},
        {"Indiana" , "Indianapolis"},
        {"Iowa" , "Des Moines"},
        {"Kansas" , "Topeka"},
        {"Kentucky" , "Frankfurt"},
        {"Louisiana" , "Baton Rouge"},
        {"Maryland" , "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusetts" , "Boston"},
        {"Michigan" , "Lansing"},
        {"Minnesota" , "Saint Paul"},
        {"Mississippi" , "Jackson"},
        {"Missouri" , "Jefferson City"},
        {"Montana" , "Helena"},
        {"Nebraska" , "Lincoln"},
        {"Nevada" , "Carson City"},
        {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey" , "Trenton"},
        {"New Mexico" , "Santa Fe"},
        {"New York" , "Albany"},
        {"North Carolina" , "Raleigh"},
        {"North Dakota" , "Bismarck"},
        {"Ohio" , "Columbus"},
        {"Oklahoma" , "Oklahoma City"},
        {"Oregon" , "Salem"},
        {"Pennsylvania" , "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island" , "Providence"},
        {"South Carolina" , "Columbia"},
        {"South Dakota" , "Pierre"},
        {"Tennessee" , "Nashville"},
        {"Texas" , "Austin"},
        {"Utah" , "Salt Lake City"},
        {"Vermont" , "Montpelier"},
        {"Virginia" , "Richmond"},
        {"Washington" , "Olympia"},
        {"West Virginia" , "Charleston"},
        {"Wisconsin" , "Madison"},
        {"Wyoming" , "Cheyenne"}
};

int correctCount = 0;
string capital;

for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
   {
     cout << "What is the capital of " << stateCapital[i][0] << "?" << flush;
     getline(cin, capital);

       if (capital==stateCapital[i][1])
         {
           cout << "Your answer is correct" << endl;
         }
    else 
         {
           cout << "The correct answer should be " << stateCapital[i][1] << endl;
         }
   }

cout << "The correct count is " << correctCount << endl;
return 0;
}
```